# Update SQL row if exists, create if does not exist (in PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a value for a user without knowing if the user exists or not.

Basically: If the user does not exist, create it, and update the value. If it does exist, update the value.

Am I using `ON DUPLICATE` properly? Can I use `WHERE` while using `ON DUPLICATE`?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Users ('$column_name[$i]') VALUES ('$value[$i]') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE '$column_name[$i]'='$value[$i]' WHERE LoginName = '$login_name'";
```

The error I am getting with this line is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''record_id') VALUES ('5287469') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 'record_id' at line 1
```

Any suggestions on how I should form my query?

Comment: What is the value of $column_name[$i]?

Comment: @SimonR It would be `record_id` for this example, which exists in the table.

Comment: Try to do a INSERT from a SELECT query with your own conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause cannot be used with an `INSERT ... VALUES` statement.

It doesn't matter that there's an `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause or not.

MySQL Reference Manual reveals (in a cryptic way) that there is no `WHERE` clause in an `INSERT ... VALUES` statement:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

(An `INSERT ... SELECT` statement can include a `WHERE` clause, in the `SELECT` part of the statement, like a normal `SELECT` statement.)

---

Don't use single quotes around identifiers (e.g. column names).

If those need to be escaped, use single backtick characters.

---

Including potentially unsafe values in SQL text throws wide open a whole slew of nasty vulnerabilities, categorized as SQL Injection.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

It could be the values being included in the SQL text have been properly sanitized, or whitelisted. But we're not seeing that in the code, so alarm bells are ringing.

---

Normative pattern (of just the SQL) would be something like this:

```
 INSERT INTO Users
 ( `primary_or_unique_key_column` 
 , `some_column_name` 
 ) VALUES 
 ( 'safe_unique_key_value'
 , 'safe_column_value'
 )
 ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE `some_column_name` = VALUES(`some_column_name`)
```

---

If `LoginName` is the PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY in the table

```
 INSERT INTO Users
 ( `loginname`
 , `record_id` 
 ) VALUES 
 ( 'safe_loginname_value'
 , 'safe_record_id_value'
 )
 ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE `record_id` = VALUES(`record_id`)
```

Note that usage of backticks around the column names, and single quotes around literal string values.

Also note the usage of the `VALUES` function, to reference the value that would have been inserted into the column, if the INSERT had been successful. (Avoids us having to provide the same value twice.

Using prepared statements with bind placeholders, we would need to properly validate the column name that's being incorporated into the SQL text (to avoid SQL Injection vulnerabilities... but the *values* can be passed in via placeholders.

The SQL text would look like this:

```
 INSERT INTO Users
 ( `loginname`
 , `record_id` 
 ) VALUES 
 ( ?
 , ?
 )
 ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE `record_id` = VALUES(`record_id`)
```

And code (assuming PDO) would be of the form:

```
$sth=$dbh->prepare($sql_text);
# check return from prepare

$sth->bindValue(1, $loginname_val, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(2, $record_id_val, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$sth->execute();
# check return from execute
```